# ¿Por qué recibo este error? "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql

Necesito ayuda colegas, estoy intentando realizar un UPDATE, al ejecutar la sentencia me tira el siguiente error:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$datosSQL = 
            [$data['nom'], 
            $data['ape'], 
            $data['pass'], 
            $data['gen'], 
            $data['nac'], 
            $data['ema'], 
            $data['rol'], 
            $data['sts']];

$sql = "UPDATE user SET 
        nom_user=:nom, 
        ape_user=:ape, 
        pass_user=:pass, 
        gen_user=:gen, 
        nac_user=:nac, 
        ema_user=:ema, 
        rol_user=:rol, 
        sts_user=:sts 
        WHERE usr_user = 'rperaza'";

$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt->execute($datosSQL)) {
    $response = array( 'ID' => '00', 'DESCRIPTION' => 'Solicitud procesada con éxito');
} else {
    $response = array( 'ID' => '02', 'DESCRIPTION' => 'No se pudo procesar la solicitud');
}
```

Comment: estás pasando algún parámetro de más

Comment: Debes pasar un array de parámetros.

Answer (score 2):

Ya resolví.. Era en los **$datosSQL** que le enviaba al **$stmt->execute()** estaba mal..

Modificando el parametro a enviar quedo de la siguiente manera y me funciono:

```
$datosSQL = array(
                    'nom' => $data['nom'],
                    'ape' => $data['ape'], 
                    'pass' => $data['pass'], 
                    'gen' => $data['gen'], 
                    'nac' => $data['nac'], 
                    'ema' => $data['ema'], 
                    'rol' => $data['rol'], 
                    'sts' => $data['sts'], 
                    'user' => $data['user']
                );
```